# IIS SMTP to create emails as file

Tags: iis, exchange, smtp, filesystems, offline-files

Is it possible to configure IIS SMTP to receive emails from client and store into a file? Yes? How?

My company does not allow email communication on our secure domain (long story). So in order to receive notifications from automated systems, backup servers etc I have installed a open source tool call “EMailRelay”. This tool listen on port 25 and receive emails from client, but its setup to write those emails into files. We then move these files into another domain. On this 2nd domain we have another instance of “EMailRelay” running, it scans the folder where we copy these email files and forward them to exchange server.

I am wondering if IIS SMTP can do similar task because I prefer to use IIS SMTP.

Domain A
It should listen and receive emails but write them to file. It should not lock the file and should not move them to bad folder. We will move these files to Domain B

Domain B
Scan folder (where the files came from Domain A) and forward those email files to Exchange.

Sorry I am new to IT world, do not hesitate to contact me if something is not clear.

Many Thanks
David

Comment: This is email. It's a convoluted way to do email, but it's still email. The alert systems are sending messages using SMTP to a receiving server. This server then transports the messages through a convoluted pipe, resulting in email being received on your exchange server. How does this not break the "company does not allow email communication on our secure domain" rule?

Answer (score 2):

The IIS SMTP server does this already by design. What you're looking for is the drop folder. You'll need to make the SMTP server think that it is the mailroot for the secure domain, and after that, it'll start putting emails it receives for that domain in the drop folder. See [How the SMTP Service works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa480390.aspx) for more information.